# Getting URL of a website using a sniffer

Tags: wireshark, network-discovery

This is my first post here.
I am currently working on a project, and I am supposed to get the URL of a website I am browsing using a sniffer (such as wireshark).
So, what I have done is look at the HTTP packets in wireshark, and there the url is displayed and accessable. The problem is
websites that use HTTPS (Secure), and not just HTTP- because the data in the packets is encrypted, I am unable to find the URL (there are no http packets to look at).
I eventually am supposed to write a python script for doing this-meaning that when a user browses different websites, the script will create a txt document with a list of all the websites the user browsed.
I have been trying to figure this out for days, but haven't managed to do so :\
I would really really appreciate some help :)
Thank you in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask about writing your program on [so].

Answer (score 1):

For encrypted traffic, really, the only thing you can find is the host of the URL, the port and perhaps the scheme. You find the host by either of the two ways:

- sniffing DNS packets and finding what host the client is trying to resolve
- performing a reverse DNS lookup for the address the client is communicating with

Of these methods, the DNS sniffing is the most reliable, as an IP address can run many websites with different hosts on it.

You cannot find the path of the URL, as the purpose of the encryption is to hide that from evil sniffers. The port can be found (it's usually 443), and you can also try to guess the scheme from the port (if 443, it's HTTPS), but that's about all you can do.